# odoo tax calculation is not correct

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

I created a supplier invoice whose amount without taxes = 5125,000.
In my country we add a tax of 1% on the total amount of the invoice without taxes so 5125,000 + 1% = 5176,25 then we add the taxes on the products which is in this case 19% for all products 5176 , 250 + 19% = 6159.7375
. Finally I add a stamp tax of amount 0,600 of or the total equal to 6160,338

So my problem is I noticed that when calculating the amount of the tax 19% there is an error odoo gives the result of 5176,250 + 19% = 6159,746 where the final result of my invoice is different from the actual result it gives me a total equal to 6160,346
How can I solve this problem? Any help please ?[image]